# How to fill color/make visible the canvas circle

Tags: javascript, html5-canvas

This is a canvas JavaScript code.

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="500" style="border:1px solid"></canvas>

<script>
  var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
  var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
  var radius = 50;
  var nStartX = 0;
  var nStartY = 0;
  var bIsDrawing = false;
  var putPoint = function(e) {
    nStartX = e.clientX;
    nStartY = e.clientY;
    bIsDrawing = true;
    radius = 0;
  }
  var drawPoint = function(e) {
    if (!bIsDrawing)
      return;
    var nDeltaX = nStartX - e.clientX;
    var nDeltaY = nStartY - e.clientY;
    radius = Math.sqrt(nDeltaX * nDeltaX + nDeltaY * nDeltaY);
    context.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
    context.beginPath();
    context.arc(nStartX, nStartY, radius, 0, Math.PI * 2);
    context.fill();
    context.fillStyle = 'rgba(0, 0, 0, 0)';
    context.lineWidth = 1;
    context.stroke();
  }
  var stopPoint = function(e) {
    bIsDrawing = false;
  }
  canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', putPoint);
  canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', drawPoint);
  canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', stopPoint);
</script>
```

I want radius to be shown or filled with color.

This is requirement. Start with a single left mouse click (down action) which will be the center of the circle and move the mouse without lifting the left mouse button to set the radius of the circle. The circle should be drawn as you move the mouse with radius equal to distance between the first point and the mouse position. Release the left mouse button to fix the radius. A marker is added at the point where the mouse button is released to mark that point. (This will be the point on the circumference of that circle)

Comment: The code works as expected. What's your question? You want the value of the radius to be shown on the circle while dragging?

Comment: Draw a small color-filled arc (==your marker) at the mouseup coordinate.

Comment: Yes the value as well as lineof the radius, the centre from where i started and circumference everything should be showed.

Comment: can u just send me code snippet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to get the offset to the top left of the canvas and remove that from the mouse coordinates to you can get the coordinates relative to the canvas top left.

How I would handle the mouse.

```
// get canvas offset
var canvasTopLeft = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
// create the mouse object
var mouse = {};
mouse.x = 0;
mouse.y = 0;
mouse.down = false;
mouse.buttonChanged = false;
mouse.button = 0;
mouse.origin = {};
mouse.origin.x = canvasTopLeft.left;
mouse.origin.y = canvasTopLeft.top;
// the mouse event handler handles all events 
var mouseEvent = function (e) {
    mouse.x = e.clientX - mouse.origin.x;
    mouse.y = e.clientY - mouse.origin.y;
    mouse.buttonChanged = 0;
    if (e.type === "mousedown") {
        mouse.down = true;
        mouse.buttonChanged = e.which;
    } else if (e.type === "mouseup") {
        mouse.down = false;
        mouse.buttonChanged = e.which;
    }
    update();  // updates the display
}
// add events we want to listen to;
canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', mouseEvent);
canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', mouseEvent);
canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', mouseEvent);
```

The snippet show how I use it to draw circles with position and radius marked.

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width="500" height="500" style="border:1px solid"></canvas>

<script>
// constants
const TICK_SIZE = 5;
const GIZOM_SIZE = 3;
const CIRCLE_STYLE = "BLACK";
const CIRCLE_LINE_WIDTH = 1;
const FONT = "18px Arial";
const FONT_STYLE = "RED";

var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

// array of circles;
var circles = [];
// current circle being drawn
var currentCircle = null;
// true if mouse dragging
var dragging = false;

// draws a circle;
function drawCircle(circle) {
var nx,
ny;
ctx.strokeStyle = CIRCLE_STYLE;
ctx.lineWidth = CIRCLE_LINE_WIDTH;

// draw circle
if (!circle.showGizom) {
    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(circle.x, circle.y, circle.r, 0, Math.PI * 2);
    ctx.stroke();
} else {
    // calculate the radius
    var nx = circle.gx - circle.x;
    var ny = circle.gy - circle.y;
    circle.r = Math.sqrt(nx * nx + ny * ny);

    ctx.beginPath();
    ctx.arc(circle.x, circle.y, circle.r, 0, Math.PI * 2);
    // draw center tick
    ctx.moveTo(circle.x - TICK_SIZE, circle.y - TICK_SIZE);
    ctx.lineTo(circle.x + TICK_SIZE, circle.y + TICK_SIZE);
    ctx.moveTo(circle.x + TICK_SIZE, circle.y - TICK_SIZE);
    ctx.lineTo(circle.x - TICK_SIZE, circle.y + TICK_SIZE);

    // draw radius line
    ctx.moveTo(circle.x, circle.y);
    ctx.lineTo(circle.gx, circle.gy);

    // draw gizom
    ctx.moveTo(circle.gx - GIZOM_SIZE, circle.gy - GIZOM_SIZE);
    ctx.lineTo(circle.gx + GIZOM_SIZE, circle.gy + GIZOM_SIZE);
    ctx.moveTo(circle.gx + GIZOM_SIZE, circle.gy - GIZOM_SIZE);
    ctx.lineTo(circle.gx - GIZOM_SIZE, circle.gy + GIZOM_SIZE);

    ctx.stroke();

    // draw radius
    ctx.font = FONT;
    ctx.fillStyle = FONT_STYLE;
    ctx.textAlign = "center";
    // get the transform to draw the text
    nx /= circle.r; // normalise the vector from center to gizom
    ny /= circle.r;
    if(nx < 0){ // is text upside down
        // set the transform to be the revers and from the gizom
        ctx.setTransform(-nx, -ny, ny, -nx, circle.gx, circle.gy);
    } else {
        ctx.setTransform(nx, ny, -ny, nx, circle.x, circle.y);
    }
    ctx.fillText(circle.r.toFixed(1), circle.r / 2, 0);

    ctx.setTransform(1, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0); // restore transform
}
}
// draw all circles;
function drawCircles() {
var i = 0,
len = circles.length;
for (; i < len; i++) {
    drawCircle(circles[i]);
}
}
// render everything
function render() {
ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
drawCircles();
}
// create a new circle
function createCircle(x, y) {
return currentCircle = {
    x : x,
    y : y,
    r : 0,
    gx : x, // gizom location
    gy : y,
    showGizom : true,
};
}

// get canvas offset
var canvasTopLeft = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
// create the mouse object
var mouse = {};
mouse.x = 0;
mouse.y = 0;
mouse.down = false;
mouse.buttonChanged = false;
mouse.button = 0;
mouse.origin = {};
mouse.origin.x = canvasTopLeft.left;
mouse.origin.y = canvasTopLeft.top;
// the mouse event handler
var mouseEvent = function (e) {
mouse.x = e.clientX - mouse.origin.x;
mouse.y = e.clientY - mouse.origin.y;
mouse.buttonChanged = 0;
if (e.type === "mousedown") {
    mouse.down = true;
    mouse.buttonChanged = e.which;
} else if (e.type === "mouseup") {
    mouse.down = false;
    mouse.buttonChanged = e.which;
}
update();
}
// add events we want to listen to;
canvas.addEventListener('mousedown', mouseEvent);
canvas.addEventListener('mousemove', mouseEvent);
canvas.addEventListener('mouseup', mouseEvent);

// function to update mouse interaction
function update() {
//if (mouse.down || dragging) { // while the is a need to render
    if (mouse.buttonChanged === 1) { // is the left button changed
        if (mouse.down) { // is it down
            if (currentCircle !== null) { // is there a circle active ??
                currentCircle.showGizom = false; // turn off its gizom
            }
            circles.push(createCircle(mouse.x, mouse.y)); // create a new circle at mouse
            dragging = true; // flag that we are dragging
        } else {
            dragging = false; // stop dragging
        }
    }
    if (dragging) { // while dragging move the circle gizom
        currentCircle.gx = mouse.x;
        currentCircle.gy = mouse.y;
    }
    // draw any updates
    render();
//}
}

</script>
```